# groups of order $p^5$ and exponent p

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

We know that a group of order $p^5$ is an extra special group. How we can show it doesn't have any abelian subgroup of order $p^4$? Also what is the presentation of this group if its exponent is equal to $p$ ?

Comment: I think what you write is ambiguous. There are groups of order $p^{5}$ which are not extra-special. Do you mean that you are given a group of order $p^{5},$ and you are told that it is extra-special, and then you are asking about further properties?

Comment: Yes there are, but I want to know the structure of a extra special of order $p^5$.

Comment: I want to ask again this question in clear way. Let $G$ be a group of order $p^5$ and exponent equal to $p$, such that $G$ be an extra special group. I want to show it doesn't have abelian subgroup of order $p^4$ and I want to know what is the presentation of this group

Answer (score 5):

If $P$ is an extraspecial non-Abelian $p$-group of order $p^{5},$ then $Z(P) = [P,P] = \Phi(P)$ has order $p,$ so is cyclic, say equal to $\langle z \rangle.$ Then $P/Z(P)$ is an elementary Abelian group of order $p^{4},$ and may be viewed as a $4$-dimensional vector space $V$ over $F,$  the field with $p$-elements.

The vector space $V$ admits a well defined non-degenerate alternating $F$-bilinear form $\langle, \rangle :V \times V \to F$ by setting $\langle xZ(P),yZ(P) \rangle = j1_{F}$ if $[x,y] = z^{j},$ (where $0 \leq j \leq p-1$).

If $A$ is an Abelian subgroup of $P$ containing $Z(P),$ then $A/Z(P) \leq \left( A/Z(P) \right)^{\perp},$ so $A/Z(P)$ is at most $2$-dimensional, as the form is non-degenerate.
Hence $|A| \leq p^{3}.$

An alternative proof may be constructed with some knowledge of character theory. If $P$ had an Abelian subgroup $A$ of order $p^{4},$ then by Clifford's theorem, every irreducible character of $P$ of degree greater than $1$ is induced from a degree $1$ irreducible character of $A,$ so has degree at most $p.$ However, $P$ has $p-1$ complex irreducible characters of degree $p^{2}$ and $p^{4}$ irreducible characters of degree $1,$ so there can be no such $A.$

Comment: Note that the fact that $P$ has exponent $p$ has not been used yet. I leave the question of the presentation, which is straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that up to isomorphisem just there exists one such an extraspecial non abelian group of order $p^5$ and exponent $p$. Is it true that this group is generated by 5 elements, say $x_1$,...$x_5$, such that $x_1$ commutes with all $x_i$, where $1\leq i\leq5$, except one of them?

Comment: The group can be generated by $4$ elements $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}$ such that $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ both commute with $x_{3}$ and $x_{4},$ but we have $[x_{1},x_{2}] = [x_{3},x_{4}] \neq 1.$ Also, $[[x_{1},x_{2}],x_{j}] = 1$ for $ 1 \leq j \leq 4.$

Answer (score -1):

Whether, in the above example, the equation C_P(x)=Z(P) , (x is not in Z(P)), holds or not?
In fact, I am looking for a 2-group such that P/Z(P) is an elementary abelian, but
C_P(x)≠Z(P) .

Comment: This is not the place for follow up questions, please instead post a new question (if you are sure that it is not already answered) and link to this question.